# How can you create an application wide screensize constant

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to know how to create an application wide (global) set of variables for detecting  the current screen size?

For instance, at the moment, I do this in each class I create.

```
//.h
@property (assign) CGRect screenRect;
@property (assign) CGFloat screenWidth;
@property (assign) CGFloat screenHeight;

//.m
@synthesize screenRect;
@synthesize screenWidth;
@synthesize screenHeight;

screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

But I would like it where I could just call screenWidth or height from any class and not have to define them every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, here's one:

Create a Header File called something like Constants.h and add this:

```
#define ScreenWidth ((int) [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)
#define ScreenHeight ((int) [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
```

then wherever you want to use it

```
#import "Constants.h"
```

Use like so:

```
NSLog(@"The ScreenWidth Is: %i", ScreenWidth);
NSLog(@"The ScreenHeight Is: %i", ScreenHeight);
```